# Visual Studio Debugging Issue: The breakpoint will not be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2019 with 4 C# projects in it. The startup project is my Web project using local IIS to run my web application, and then control will jump to different C# files in other projects. Control can hit breakpoints in the other projects, but I cannot get my breakpoints to work in one project. When I load the web application and try to stop at a breakpoint, they are not hit, and the application finishes what it was doing. Unfortunately, I need to be able to debug the project. It is skipping to look for a bug in the code.  The error I get when I hover over the breakpoint is "The breakpoint will not be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound."

I have been searching for hours on google and trying all different suggestions and nothing is working.

- Visual studio is set to Debug (Not release).
- I tried cleaning the solution, restarting visual studio, deleting the .vs folder, and rebuilding.
- When I tried to make the project with the breakpoints as my default start up and using debugging to attach to a process it gives me another error that says it cannot load the symbols.
- The configuration manager is all set to debug
- Define DEBUG constant and Trace constant is checked
- Optimize code is unchecked

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it! I am still learning and new to visual studio and I have no idea why I cannot stop at the breakpoint and I been at this for hours! Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what is happening. I will take a guess at what is happening. Something important to understand is that the VS debugger can debug only one process at a time. A possible solution is to use a second instance of VS. However the most important problem is _it gives me another error that says it cannot load the symbols_. Perhaps you **only** need to solve that problem.

Comment: When you say _C# files in other projects_ do you mean other applications (processes)?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'm sorry if my post wasn't very clear. This is my first post so I tried to be clear. My start-up project is my web project. The debugger loads the web application using localhost in chrome. I need control to stop at a line in a CS file located in another project but in the same solution. The other project is an application that runs as a Windows service. If I run it by pressing the green play button the breakpoint says  breakpoint out of bounds. If I run the debugger by attaching to a process (chrome window) I get the symbols aren't loaded error.